# What is gxres.rc?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a VC++ 6 application that is developed on old 32bit machines. The application is developed for 32bit machines, but can be run on 64bit machines - almost.
Some dialogs don't open.

Trying to debug - I have succesfully installed VC++ 6 onto a Windows 7 64bit machine. Upon compiling the project, the compiler says:
"**fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'gxres.rc'.**"

What is **gxres.rc**?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't installed all libraries that are used to build the project.

When I google for gxres.rc I find links on http://www.roguewave.com So you may have a library or parts of your code relay on other source code that isn't installed on the machine.

But you don't need to build on the target machine to debug the file. Just install VC6, place the source code and the exe with the PDB file on the machine an debug.

Also there may be still a chance to use the old remote debug features of VC6.

My last tipp: Don't use VC6 any longer... upgrade to a current version of VS!